# Unnest json-style-like cells across multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering what the best way is to unnest the json-style-like cells across multiple columns. I tried `pd.json_normalize()` from `pandas` and it didn't seem to work. Any better idea?

```
                                             authors                                      author_detail                                       title_detail                                    media_thumbnail
1  [{'name': '/u/Ashamed_Boss2510', 'href': 'http...  {'name': '/u/Ashamed_Boss2510', 'href': 'https...  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...                                                NaN
2  [{'name': '/u/lazywizard99', 'href': 'https://...  {'name': '/u/lazywizard99', 'href': 'https://w...  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  [{'url': 'https://external-preview.redd.it/fcU...
3  [{'name': '/u/Guy_PCS', 'href': 'https://www.r...  {'name': '/u/Guy_PCS', 'href': 'https://www.re...  {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base...  [{'url': 'https://external-preview.redd.it/L-W...
```

Dput:

```
df = "pd.DataFrame({'authors': pd.Series([[{'name': '/u/Ashamed_Boss2510', 'href': 'https://www.reddit.com/user/Ashamed_Boss2510'}], [{'name': '/u/lazywizard99', 'href': 'https://www.reddit.com/user/lazywizard99'}], [{'name': '/u/Guy_PCS', 'href': 'https://www.reddit.com/user/Guy_PCS'}]],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=4, step=1)), 'author_detail': pd.Series([{'name': '/u/Ashamed_Boss2510', 'href': 'https://www.reddit.com/user/Ashamed_Boss2510'}, {'name': '/u/lazywizard99', 'href': 'https://www.reddit.com/user/lazywizard99'}, {'name': '/u/Guy_PCS', 'href': 'https://www.reddit.com/user/Guy_PCS'}],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=4, step=1)), 'title_detail': pd.Series([{'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base': 'https://www.reddit.com/r/StockMarket/.rss', 'value': 'Always have an exit strategy!'}, {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base': 'https://www.reddit.com/r/StockMarket/.rss', 'value': 'Nikola reports yet another loss with $0 revenue'}, {'type': 'text/plain', 'language': None, 'base': 'https://www.reddit.com/r/StockMarket/.rss', 'value': 'This crypto scam bilked investors out of $11 million — and paid action star Steven Seagal to promote it. What was left unsaid was that Seagal was being paid to be a spokesman, with the promise of $250,000 plus $750,000 in B2G coin for his time, the SEC said.'}],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=4, step=1)), 'media_thumbnail': pd.Series([nan, [{'url': 'https://external-preview.redd.it/fcUXTQfhTGh8Pgf3r-NT8tejZU7c-e73eylUXQmsjGk.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=b23eeb929e75fb34da96509017784b9e29a0974f'}], [{'url': 'https://external-preview.redd.it/L-WoVKyLp1qifGqMEXat-zP64V9qW-pfE_4brQwU_fg.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=bea54909841c2ca86571494226c47deb9c2a9d2e'}]],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=4, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=4, step=1))"
```

Comment: Please could you include a reproducible example that we can copy-paste?

Comment: Thanks @not_speshal - it has been added.

Comment: Could you also include your expected output? It looks like the columns `authors` and `author_detail` are exactly the same.

Comment: just look up how to handle embedded lists and dicts.  lists is typically `explode()`, dicts `appy(pd.Series)`

Comment: Oh yes, they're likely the same - authors and author detail. My goal is to make a dataframe with all the unested columns. Instead of having authors, we can column like name, href ... and so on. @not_speshal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parsing each column into a DataFrame and then concatenate all the columns together, like so:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: {} if pd.isnull(x) else x) #replace np.nan with empty dictionaries
list_of_df = list()
for column in df.columns:
    list_of_df.append(pd.concat(df[column].fillna(dict).apply(pd.DataFrame, index=[0]).tolist()))
result = pd.concat(list_of_df, axis=1)

>>> result
                 name  ...                                                url
0  /u/Ashamed_Boss2510  ...                                                NaN
0      /u/lazywizard99  ...  https://external-preview.redd.it/fcUXTQfhTGh8P...
0           /u/Guy_PCS  ...  https://external-preview.redd.it/L-WoVKyLp1qif...
```